# PHP Pregreplace замена pattern

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Есть регулярка для замены `bbcode`-смайла:

```
return preg_replace('#\[smile\](\d+)\[/smile\]#', 
'<img src="https://site.com/assets/img/smiles/$1.gif?2" class="smileicon">', 
 $text);
```

Но проблема в том, что смайлов всего  - 36. А если ввести `[smile]37[/smile]` то выведется пустая 404 картинка. Не подскажите как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно рассмотреть пару вариантов.

Первый - использовать [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php), с проверкой допустимости числового значения. Примерно так:

```
$data = [ "[smile]36[/smile]", "[smile]37[/smile]"];


foreach($data as $text){
    $out =  preg_replace_callback('#\[smile\](\d+)\[/smile\]#',.
                function($matches){
                    if($matches[1] < 37){
                        return '<img src="https://site.com/assets/img/smiles/'.$matches[1].'.gif?2" class="smileicon">';
                    }
                    return $matches[0];
                }, $text);
    print_r($out);
}
```

второй - составить регулярку, которая будет соответствовать только диапазону 1-36, какую нить а-ля

```
#\[smile\]([1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-6])\[\/smile\]#
```

Comment: Мне более подходит второй вариант, но дело в том что картинка в виде  [smile]37[/smile] все равно отображается, а по идее должен быть просто текст вместо неё

Comment: @Владимир поясните. Если подставить эту регулярку в ваш код, то для 37 никакой замены не происходит. Если же у вас уже что-то ранее было заменено, и выводится, то к вопросу это не относится.

Answer (score 1):

Если имеенно регуляркой

```
#\[smile\]([012]\d|3[0-6])\[/smile\]#
```

[можно попробовать тут :)](https://regex101.com/r/Wv9Fpv/1)